# Controlling an electromagnetic switch with Reed switches

Tags: relay, electromagnetism, reed-switch

I'm trying to power a 12v electromagnetic switch using NO reed switches.

IE: when the 5 reed switches all have magnets near them then the elecromagnet switch unlocks something. However, I'm trying to figure out a way to just turn the elecromagnet switch on for 1 or 2 seconds then turn it off so it doesn't overheat without removing the magnets from the reed switches.

I know there's time delay relays that won't turn the relay on until X seconds, is there a relay that will turn off after X seconds?

Comment: By "electromagnetic switch" I suspect you mean a solenoid? What current does the solenoid take?

Comment: yeah sorry, it's rated at 1.3a

Comment: There are such relays, I believe the function is called On Pulse. They turn on for a time then turn off. I hate links that can fade away but this is the best I can give .... who knew there were so many options.. http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=info/timer

Comment: A solenoid typically has a very low holding current.  When the armature is in the "energized" position, the current through the solenoid drops well below its rating.  Are you sure you need to de-energize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use a large capacitor in series with the reed switches and the magnet. When the reed switches close, current will flow though the capacitor (and thus the magnet) at first, but as the capacitor charges it will conduct less and less current. You should add a resistor across the capacitor leads so it can discharge when the switches open.
2. Use a 555 timer circuit in one-shot mode.
3. Get a [commercial timer board](http://amzn.to/1UJMvRC) designed for exactly this purpose.